Mod $\ell$ Cyclotomic Character Evaluated at Frobenius Away From $\ell$
Let $\ell$ be a prime, let $p \neq \ell$ be prime, and let $P$ be a prime lying above $p$ in $\overline{\mathbb Z}$, the ring of integers of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. If $\chi_\ell$ is the $\ell$-adic cyclotomic character, how do I see that
$$\chi_\ell(\operatorname{Frob}_P) = p$$
regardless of how $p$ or $P$ were chosen? The way I understand it is that $\chi_\ell(\operatorname{Frob}_P) = (m_1,m_2,...)$, where $\operatorname{Frob}_P(\mu_{\ell^n}) = \mu_{\ell^n}^{m_n}$ for each $n$ and $\mu_{\ell^n}$ represents a primitive $\ell^n$th root of unity. Is it not the case that all the $m_i$ are just $p$?
One issue is that I am not sure how to evaluate $\operatorname{Frob}_P(\mu_{\ell^n})$, since I only know how Frobenius acts mod $P$ (which is as the $p$th power).
I have already read and failed to understand the answer to a similar question here.
